# Is it necessary to reassign Blazor class properties assigned from URL route parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

When I first started to learn Blazor the tutorials I followed would reassign the class properties for a page assigned by URL parameters to new class properties like this:

```
//URL = "/pagename/{parameter1}/{parameter2}"
[Parameter]
public string parameter1 { get; set; }
public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string parameter2 { get; set; }
public string Parameter2 { get; set; }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   Parameter1 = parameter1;
   Parameter2 = parameter2;
}
```

Why would I not just assign the URL parameters to the page's properties I want to use in the first place? This way I avoid the extra code and processing.

```
//URL = "/pagename/{Parameter1}/{Parameter2}"
[Parameter]
public string Parameter1 { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public string Parameter2 { get; set; }
```

Is there a reason why I would want to use the first way over the second way? If so what is it?

*Edited for accuracy and clarity as suggested in comments.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#overwritten-parameters

Comment: No clue what tutorial you were following, but I've been using Blazor since the beginning and have never seen anyone suggest this pattern.

Comment: @GSerg, please, remove your comment. It is wrong and misleading.

Comment: @enet Care to explain why? It would appear it is [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70809866/11683) that contradicts the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#overwritten-parameters). The pattern to copy the received parameters into private variables and then working with those exists to avoid parameter overwriting.

Comment: @GSerg, the question has nothing to do with component parameters. It's about route parameters. "Overwritten parameters" is an issue related to component parameter properties that are modified or mutate by the component. See a good explanation to the wrong question in the answer by Mister Magoo.

Comment: @enet The last paragraph of the answer by Mister Magoo, which is the only one concerning URL parameters, suggests that the underlying issue is the same, and though it's unlikely you will want to overwrite them, this technique will protect you if you do. If the underlying reason is the same, why is my comment misleading?

Comment: @GSerg, Sorry, I did not read the whole answer then. However, the question has nothing to do with "Overwritten parameters". This renders your comment wrong. As for the last paragraph, suggesting that the  underlying issue is the same;  you're wrong. It does not suggest that. And if it does, it is not true. The issue is completely different. His conclusion that the OP's  "tutorials did this tactic of working with a local copy", is baseless. I've never seen such a practice employed, by the new learners  of Blazor, in the docs, or any Blazor tutorials. What for???

Comment: I guess that the asker of the question is simply wrong in suggesting that that was the case then. Would he also claim that the parameter properties where defined without public access modifiers, or that the route template looked like this: "/pagename/{parameter1}/{parameter2}." The route template is not complete...

Comment: [Polite] Gents, Tyson asked a simple question.  There's no clues as to how he's using the parameters: everyone is just guessing!  Kirk Woll's answer is appropriate, and Enet's answer, answers the question posed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would I not just assign the URL parameters to the properties I want to use to avoid the extra code and processing like this?

```
//URL = "/pagename/{Parameter1}/{Parameter2}"

[Parameter]
string Parameter1 { get; set; }
[Parameter]
string Parameter2 { get; set; }
```

This is precisely how it has always been. Note also that the parameters' names in the route template can start with a lower-case letter (preferable).

Note: A parameter property should be public.

Comment: @TysonGibby,  I believe this answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815296/6152891

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what you are doing with the parameters.

The general rule to follow in Blazor is "components shouldn't overwrite their own incoming parameter value properties" - [Steve Sanderson's comment on this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24599#issuecomment-697518127)

Blazor tracks parameter state internally and if your component modifies the value of a parameter directly `parameter1 = "foo"` then "Blazor" does not see that change.

It is not even good enough to include a `Parameter1Changed` `EventCallback` to update the parent component as there is still a period of time between you changing the parameter value and the internal state getting updated. This can cause problems with component rendering.

So, if your component is going to update the parameter, you should always copy it to a local field/property first, update the local and the invoke your original `Parameter1Changed` EventCallback. This will allow any state to be updated.

In the case of URL parameters it is unlikely you would be updating them, but there could be a scenario where you felt it was a good idea - so that is possibly why your tutorials did this tactic of working with a local copy.

Comment: MisterMagoo , the question has nothing to do with component parameters, and everything to do with `route parameters`